# Programmatically changing value of input type file?

Tags: javascript, html, input, filelist

I'm trying to produce a bit of code that I can reuse throughout my site which is, essentially, a photos picker/chooser with some validation. Here is my code:

```
class PhotoPicker
{
    constructor(element)
    {
        this.element = element;

        //Creating needed HTML Markup
        this.createMarkUp();

        //FileList of valid data.
        this.validFiles = new DataTransfer();

        //Initialise Picker.
        this.input.onchange = () => {
            this.updateOutput();
            this.output.files = this.validFiles.files;
        }
    }

    updateOutput()
    {
        const files = Array.from(this.input.files);
        files.forEach((file) => {                
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = () => {
                photo = this.createPhotoThumb({
                    url : reader.result,
                    name: file.name,
                    size: file.size
                });
                if (this.validatePhoto(file)) {
                    this.validFiles.items.add(file);
                };
            };
        });
    }

    createMarkUp()
    {
        //Creating needed HTML Markup
    }
    createPhotoThumb(data = {})
    {
        //Creating a photo thumbnail for preview
    }
    validatePhoto(photo)
    {
        //Validating the photo
    }
}
```

What's happening is when I do the first selection of some images, thumbnails are displayed and the list of valid files `this.validFiles.files` gets updated, but ***NOT*** the final list which I plan to send to the server `this.output.files` , *however*, on a second attempt, it works! where the final list gets updated with files from the first selection and ***NOT*** the second, and so on.. with every selection the files from the previous one are added to the final list but not files from last selection.

Comment: `Class` should be with small `c` I think

Comment: It's `constructor` and not `constrctor`

Comment: Yep, both true, sorry for mistyping.. anything about the logic though? the problem itself?

Comment: [FileReader#onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload) is asynchronous. Add some logging and you'll realize that `this.createPhotoThumb` is only called (way) after your `forEach` loop has finished

Comment: Why are you creating a dataURI version of the file? If you only wish to dispaly it, then use a blob URI, that you can create synchronously using `URL.createObjectURL(blob)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you expect that

```
reader.onload = () => {
    photo = this.createPhotoThumb({
        url : reader.result,
        name: file.name,
        size: file.size
    });
    if (this.validatePhoto(file)) {
        this.validFiles.items.add(file);
    };
};
```

get's executed before you assign the valid files to `this.output.files`.

But `reader.onload` get executed asynchronously, so that your assignment of the valid files to `this.output.files` gets executed before the valid files are added to the array of valid files.

You have to implement some logic that waits for the completeness of the `onload` handlers of your readers.

This would be a possible solution:

```
class PhotoPicker
{
    constructor(element)
    {
        this.element = element;

        // Creating needed HTML Markup
        this.createMarkUp();

        // FileList of valid data.
        this.validFiles = new DataTransfer();

        // Initialise Picker.
        this.input.onchange = () => {
            this.updateOutput()
                .then(() => {
                    this.output.files = this.validFiles.files;
                });
        }
    }

    updateOutput()
    {
        const files = Array.from(this.input.files);
        const fileLoaderPromises = [];
        files.forEach((file) => {
            const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                reader.onload = () => {
                    photo = this.createPhotoThumb({
                        url : reader.result,
                        name: file.name,
                        size: file.size
                    });
                    if (this.validatePhoto(file)) {
                        this.validFiles.items.add(file);
                    };
                    // Mark the file loader as "done"
                    resolve();
                };
            })

            // Add the promise to the list of file loader promises
            fileLoaderPromises.push(promise);
        });

        // Return a promise which resolves as soon as all file loader promises are done
        return Promise.all(fileLoaderPromises);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Code review, instead of a `forEach`, use `Promise.all(files.filter().map((file) => ...))` And ideally each promise would return the contents instead of modifying class state directly from that code, the code that resolves the promise should do the setting... will make the code much easier to grok

Comment: YES... that was it! I believe my limited-to-none knowledge in asynchronous / synchronous operations was the reason that got me stuck in there.
Thanks guys.. now I know what my next lesson should be :)